# Can't figure out these Blue Screens (Unexpected Store Exception / Critical Process Died)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bsod

I'm trying to figure out these couple of Blue Screens and I can't figure out what's going on. have a brand-new Thinkpad T590 (replaced the SSD with a 1TB SSD from Crucial, wasn't gonna give Lenovo $200 for it), but I'm not sure that's the problem. The PC was working fine for months and all of a sudden it started bluescreening.

I've ran `sfc /scannow` and got the following log.
[CBS.log](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=21950917491975287188&t=2195091749197528718869631)

Then I ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` which did find errors and supposedly fixed them. Running both commands now after reboots finds no errors bu the computer still reboots

Finally I ran `chkdsk C: /f /r /x` and it found no issues.

I've also tried opening the PC and reseating the SSD to no avail.

I've updated all the drivers and the BIOS/UEFI using both the Lenovo Vantage software built into the PC and the web-based driver scan tool. Everything is up to date.

The only thing I can think of that I haven't done yet, that seems to maybe cause this issue is disabling the antivirus (Webroot Secure Anywhere 9.0.26.61).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's brand new, send it in for warranty. To me, it seems you have a SATA controller that has failed or the SATA port connector has gone bad. Fixing those issues would require a new motherboard.

Comment: See the answer of AlexanderBrandy on this Microsoft Community [page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-fix-unexpected-store-exception-error/8cf70b0f-5c32-4f48-b74d-361ed6b48c79?pa)

Comment: @DrZoo I'm honestly not sure. I ran the diagnostics tests in the BIOS and also ran MemTest86. All came back normal. I believe Lenovo's diagnostic tool tests the SATA bus

Comment: @spike_66 Are you talking about the disabling of fast startup? I feel like that's patching the problem and not fixing it. It should just work

Comment: I disabled fast startup recently, because after upgrading to build 18999 my PC didn't shut down properly and when holding the start button to shut it down, it restarted, perhaps on a wake-on-lan request. With fast startup disabled the problem has never occurred again. I have noticed a delay in booting of about ten seconds (Samsung 860 1 TB SSD). On this [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) pros and cons of fast startup.

Comment: @audiFanatic Fast Startup is just a Microsoft gimmick to give the appearance that Windows boots fast. It has the potential to create problems and actually solves none. Think of disabling it and a temporary workaround. A UEFI update might correct the underlying issue very soon, if not already.